# How to use OdataNextLink in Microsoft Graph API Beta 5

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I was using the Microsoft Graph API 1.0 but have updated to the Beta in order to use CustomSecurityAttributeValue support.
I've managed to port most of the code but I can't see any way to process multiple results pages.

Previously you would just do something like

```
if (membersPage.NextPageRequest != null)
    membersPage = await membersPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
```

But NextPageRequest no longer exists, the only available information is OdataNextLink which is a string with no obvious way to request the next page or create a raw request using the url.

Code I have so far:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.User>> GetGraphUsersInGroups(IEnumerable<string> groupIds, string? searchText = null)
        {
            Dictionary<String, Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.User> users = new Dictionary<String, Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.User>();
   
            foreach (var groupId in groupIds)
            {
                try
                {                  
                    var membersPage = await GraphClient.Groups[groupId].Members
                        .GetAsync((memberRequest) => {
                            memberRequest.Headers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("$count", "true"));
                            memberRequest.Headers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));
                            memberRequest.QueryParameters.Count = true;
                            memberRequest.QueryParameters.Orderby = new[] { "displayName" };
                            if (searchText != null)
                                memberRequest.QueryParameters.Search = $"\"displayName:{searchText}\"";
                        });

                    while (membersPage != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var member in membersPage.Value.OfType<Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.User>())
                        {
                            users[member.Id] = member;
                        }
                        if (membersPage.OdataNextLink != null)
                        {
                            // How to use membersPage.OdataNextLink???
                        }
                        else
                            break;
                    }   
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }

            return users.Values;

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried the same through graph explorer- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer , are still still facing the same issue there or it happens only for SDKs?

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to. The question is specifically about how to get the next page. Graph explorer isn't going to help with that.

Comment: Actually, I want to check is there next page exist , are you getting @odata.nextLink , when you call API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members .

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.

Comment: Might be , could you please help me to understand , correct me if i am wrong, in your code you are unable to get the OdataNextLink , right?

Comment: Vicky Kumar, the point is that people are trying to use the Nuget package (in my case Microsoft.Graph 5.8).  Telling C# developers to go use the rest api directly with curl to see if it works better is meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the PageIterator, see an example below:

```
var users = new List<User>();
var userResponse = await serviceClient.Users.GetAsync((builder) => {
   // builder.SomeStuff      
});
// Added the namespace here, just for some clarity :-)
var pageIterator = Microsoft.Graph.PageIterator<User,UserCollectionResponse>
                     .CreatePageIterator(serviceClient, userResponse, (user) => 
                          { 
                               users.Add(user.Id); 
                               return true; });

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

Comment: This example is incomplete.  What do you do with this pageIterator object after you create it?  How do you start it, stop it, wait for it to be done?

Btw, Microsoft Graph SDK is literally the world's worst API SDK.  It is so unbelievably wierd, poorly designed, and poorly documented.

Comment: The latest v5 changelog has a good example. 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/4db835fbbecb46e89341df54399e91c17c96b0cc/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#pageiterator

Comment: I agree with A X. MS absolutely sucks with this "Graph"... as whoever is on the team just keeps re-inventing themself, to the point that you can't find the correct version documentation!... or then it's just a doc for the rest api directly, not the C# library.

This example does work for me.  I'm loading groups, so it's:

var oQuery2 = await oClient.Users[user.Id].TransitiveMemberOf.GetAsync();

and then
PageIterator<Microsoft.Graph.Models.DirectoryObject, DirectoryObjectCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator

If you don't get those types exactly right, you will get weird errors.

Comment: Since 5.0 is now out of beta, for anyone looking for a complete example, there are at least some tips and help on the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 3):

There is a not yet documented way to use the **OdataNextLink** for the next client call, PageIterator was not appropriate for my needs so after a long time digging I've found this, that works fine to me

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync(o =>
{
    o.QueryParameters.Top = 2;
    o.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName" };
});

var nextPageLink = users.OdataNextLink;

Console.WriteLine("Page 1");
users.Value.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.DisplayName));

var nextPageRequestInformation = new RequestInformation
{
    HttpMethod = Method.GET,
    UrlTemplate = nextPageLink
};

var nextPageResult = await graphClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(nextPageRequestInformation, (parseNode) => new UserCollectionResponse());

Console.WriteLine("Page 2");
nextPageResult.Value.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.DisplayName));
```